# How to share attachments from user to agent (Human handoff) using Bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, attachment, azure-language-understanding, handoff

i have bot made using c#. It has the feature of human off. We have integrated the solution provide by tompanna of human handoff where a agent can talk to single user at a time.Here the link of solution we used for human handoff https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample. Our bot is working fine and able to talk with agent with the help of this solution but major issue come when a user want to share image or any kind of attachments from user to agent or from agent to user. The bot show that image is send but user is not able to see it. Simpler case happen in the case of agent.
[image]
 Image of agent while sending a attachment to user.
[image]

And also the image of user ,unable to see the image send by agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) which you are using for Human HandOff has not been updated over a year, so it gets difficult to be able to find solutions for supporting various features pertaining to the same. However, going through the sample issues, there has been a similar [issue](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample/issues/47) in which the sample does not support emojis, images or files to the receiving user. If a user sends any of the above mentioned features, the receiver will get a blank message as it [supports](https://github.com/tompaana/bot-message-routing/blob/d10cce2ca2e7e4c83143fbbfca6af8d350a7d48c/BotMessageRouting/MessageRouting/MessageRouter.cs#L420) only text messages.

Th tentative [solution](https://github.com/tbuha/intermediator-bot-sample/commit/b43075a646044149dce55329339861912e860140) suggested by a user is to create a simple method extension to send image/file messages.You could go ahead and give it a try to see if it works for your case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the source code of the library to achieve what you are trying.

In this [MessageRouter](https://github.com/tompaana/bot-message-routing/blob/master/BotMessageRouting/MessageRouting/MessageRouter.cs) file , method RouteMessageIfSenderIsConnectedAsync , you can access message.Attachments , then pass it as a parameter to SendMessageAsync in line 432, then from SendMessageAsync in line 160 , you can pass it to CreateMessageActivity method and then in file [ConnectorClientMessageBundle](https://github.com/tompaana/bot-message-routing/blob/master/BotMessageRouting/MessageRouting/Utils/ConnectorClientMessageBundle.cs) , you can access the attachment and attach it to messageActivity.